# Migrating VMs from hyper-v server 2012 r2 to windows server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, live-migration

I'm turning in circles and I don't know what I could od more to make this work.

I have 2 hyperv 2012R2 nodes in a cluster and 3 windows server 2016 nodes in another cluster. I want to live migrate some vms from the first cluster to the second.

I took out the vms I want to move from the first cluster and from the hyper-v manager I started the move but it ends up with an error that just wont go away!

> The virtual machine 'VM01' is not compatible with physical computer 'SRVR02'

The solution I find in more forums are that the CPU are not the same, but the option to enable migration between cpu version is already on and the CPU are Intel X5660 for the nodes in the first cluster and X5680 for the second. There really should not be any reason why they would not be compatible!

I made sure everything was as close to the same as possible, added the same switch in hyper-v manager on all nodes, made sure the storage was close (C:\Clusterstorage\volume5\VM to C:\clusterstorage\colume1\VM)

I changed delegation for all nodes to kerberos (in hyper-v manager) and "any authentication protocol" in active directory delegation settings.

I tried from source and destination, powershell and remote manager, tried to close the vm, do an export, do only storage, change to all kerberos but nothing changes.

Another error I get when I try to only move storage is :

> Storage migration for virtual machine 'VM01' (alphanumbers) failed with error 'General access denied error' (0x80070005).

The folder I want the storage to go to is already shared to all the nodes, I do not know what more to add.

At first I wanted to join the hyper-v server nodes to the windos server cluster but during a test everything failed to stay online as it should (one of the reason for the upgrade) so I cannot do it from the cluster. I also cannot add the 2016 servers to the 2012 cluster, the validation wizard gives an incompatibility error for the os.

I really just need some ideas on what I can do next without completely reinstalling the new servers and preferably without closing any vms.

Comment: Rather than migrating the VM's, try exporting one of the VM's on the old cluster and importing it on the new cluster.

Comment: Exporting from the source to itself works, importing to the new server afterwards also works. I am keeping this method in case I never figure out how to do it live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was preparing myself to close all the vms and just export/import everything BUT before that I created a new admin-client (w10 1709 with RSAT) to remotely manage my servers and it had an RPC problem with the Hyperv servers. The solution to that problem was to enable the incoming rule "Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)" in the firewall of that client.

I could now manage the virtual machines of the hyperv servers and found out I can also now do a live migration remotely from the admin-client with no problem. Be it from HYPERV2012R2 to W2016 or W2016 to W2016 if I do it from that admin-client.

I do not understand how that would work if I could not do it directly in the hosts, but it did so... yay!

**EDIT**: One of the Hyperv2012r2 servers started giving me "faild at source" errors (while the other server is doing great), the solution to that problem was to open a command prompt on the source server and do "net stop vmms" and "net start vmms".

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the steps below to complete the VM migration:

1. Remove VM from 2012R2 Cluster (VM will run on the node which was owner node);
2. Open Hyper-V Manager on 2012R2 and click "Move";
3. Select "Move Virtual Machine";
4. Specify destination computer (one of the 2016 Cluster members);
5. Specify destination ( C:\ClusterStorage\volume3);
6. Click OK and wait for migration;
7. After the migration, open Failover Cluster on the 2016 cluster;
8. Navigate to the roles tab and click "Configure role";
9. Select Virtual Machine in the list and specify needed VM;
10. Wait for the VM configuration.

Comment: As written in my question, the problem I have is that if I do this it will give me an error : "The virtual machine 'VM01' is not compatible with physical computer 'SRVR02'". There is no "after migration" as that error stops everything. Also, I cannot open the manager on 2012R2 as it is not a windows server but a hyper-v server, there is no GUI.